# Conditional random forest :: saving models efficiently

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm working on a regression problem involving multiple independent learning tasks. I'm using conditional random forest as the learner (see Hothorn et al. 2006) as they are quite robust. The problem I'm having is saving the models. Multiple learning tasks means many big models.

How can I save a subset of each model without taking too much disk/memory space without compromising the usability of my models for predictions?

Comment: Is this more of an R / programming question? I can't tell for sure. If it is, it would be better asked, & probably answered, on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) rather than here. If this is a question primarily about statistics, please edit to clarify, OTOH, if you just want to know how to get R to do this, flag your Q & we can migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Comment: I agree with gung's comments. The trees may be large but not say 100's of megabytes. They should be a manageable size on disk, especially if compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

- use a newer package like ranger because it can have a smaller footprint
- save the object with the compress flag set

If you have a particular library, aka your conditional is NOT applied to existing RF libraries, then it should make a single tree of models, and just saving with compress set can be about the best you will get without manually reconstructing the save-format.

If you do NOT have a particular conditional, that is to say you are making many independent RF's, then using a relatively modern tool along with saving using the compress flag as true, can very substantially improve your results.